# Selecting a random string from a delimited text file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba, random

I'm trying to input all the parsed strings into a 2D array where the first 5 strings make up one column and then the next 5 make up the second column ect. Then I need to randomly select 3 of the columns and have every string in that column outputted.

```
        path = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("Two_Point_One_Questions.txt")
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(path.FullName)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                Dim i As Integer = 1
                Dim j As Integer = 1
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    Question(i, j) = currentField
                    j = j + 1
                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                        FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: You don't increment the variable i

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you need to increment the variable i to fill a new slot on the Question array

```
        ....
        End Try
        i = i + 1
    End While
End Using
```

By the way, arrays start at index zero, not at one. So probably your stating values for i, y are wrong

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim j As Integer = 0
```

And finally, the variable i should be declared and initialized before entering the while loop, otherwise it will be reset to its initial value and the line read from the file will go always to the same slot of your array